# Opencart update table with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, opencart

I have table that I am trying to append rows to when there is new data to display. I tried to write an Ajax query that would get custom objects from the data table. I have three stores and feedbacks to each of them.
I have controller where load all feedbacks from all stores:

```
 $totalfeedbacks = count($this->model_catalog_feedbackcrazy->getTotalFeedbacksCrazy());
    $results = $this->model_catalog_feedbackcrazy->getAllFeedbackscrazy($data);

    $this->data['stores'] = array();
    $this->data['stores'][] = $this->model_catalog_feedbackcrazy->getAllStores();
    $this->data['text_missing'] = $this->language->get('text_missing');


    if (isset($this->request->get['store_id'])) {
        $this->data['choose_store'] = $this->request->get['store_id'];
    } else {
        $this->data['choose_store'] = null;
    }

    $this->data['feedbackscrazys'] = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {

        if ($result['shop_id'] == 0) {
            $result['shop_id'] = 'BG';
        } elseif ($result['shop_id'] == 1) {
            $result['shop_id'] = 'RO';
        } else {
            $result['shop_id'] = 'EN';
        }


        $this->data['feedbackscrazys'][] = array(
            'feedback_id' => $result['feedback_id'],
            'feedback_name' => $result['form_name'],
            'feedback_date' => $result['date_added'],
            'feedback_text' => $result['feedback'],
            'feedback_rating' => $result['rating'],
            'feedback_shop_id' => $result['shop_id'],
            'feedback_email' => $result['email']
        );
    }


    $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
        'separator' => false
    );
    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
        'separator' => ' :: '
    );

    $this->data['column_mark'] = $this->language->get('column_mark');
    $this->data['column_id'] = $this->language->get('column_id');
    $this->data['column_name'] = $this->language->get('column_name');
    $this->data['column_text'] = $this->language->get('column_text');
    $this->data['column_date'] = $this->language->get('column_date');
    $this->data['column_email'] = $this->language->get('column_email');
    $this->data['column_rating'] = $this->language->get('column_rating');
    $this->data['column_shop'] = $this->language->get('shop_id');
    $this->data['button_deleteselected'] = $this->language->get('button_deleteselected');
```

....
model for ajax:

```
public function getAllFeedsByStore($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "feedbackcrazy ";
    $sql .= " WHERE shop_id = ".$id;
    $sql .= " ORDER BY feedback_id DESC";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

and my view:

```
<form action="#" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="filter-group2"  >
    <div class="heading">
        <h3><img src="view/image/why-choose-us.png" style="max-height: 30px;" alt="" /> <?php echo $filter ?></h3>

            <select name="filter_store_id" id="feeds" onchange="return ajaxFilterForm(); ">
                <?php if ($filter_store_id == '0') { ?>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_missing; ?></option>
                <?php }?>
                <option value="0"><?php echo 'Crazy Kids BG'; ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($stores[0] as $key => $store) { ?>
                <?php if ($store[$key]['store_id'] == $store['choose_store']) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $store['store_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $store['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $store['store_id']; ?>"><?php echo $store['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0"/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and part of table with feedbacks

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="feedbackcrazyform">
        <div id="allfeedbacks">
<div id="product_summary">
            <table width="80%" >
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $column_mark; ?></th>
                    <th width="5%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $column_id; ?></th>
                    <th width="10%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $column_name; ?></th>
                    <th width="40%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $column_text; ?></th>
                    <th width="10%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $column_date; ?></th>
                    <th width="15%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $column_email; ?></th>
                    <th width="10%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $shop_id; ?></th>
                    <th width="5%" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $column_rating; ?></th>

                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($feedbackscrazys as $feedback) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;" align="right"><input type="CHECKBOX" name="checktodel[<?php echo $feedback['feedback_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $feedback['feedback_id']; ?>"></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_id']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_name']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_text']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_date']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_email']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_shop_id']; ?></td>
                        <td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_rating']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
</div>
        </div>

        <div id="buttonsubm" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
        <input type="submit" name="deletefeedbacks" id="deletefeedbacks" style="padding: 5px 6px; background-color: #003A88; color: #ffffff; font-size: 13px;" class="button" value="<?php echo $button_deleteselected; ?>">
        </div>
      </form>
```

I want to replace the content of table ... but nothing's happened...

this is ajax view

```
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;" align="right"><input type="CHECKBOX" name="checktodel[<?php echo $feedback['feedback_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $feedback['feedback_id']; ?>"></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_id']; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_name']; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_text']; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_date']; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_email']; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_shop_id']; ?></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #003A88; padding: 5px 3px;"><?php echo $feedback['feedback_rating']; ?></td>
```

Comment: please share your ajax code which updates the table